# Angular 7 dynamic nested material menu from groupby pipe results

Tags: angular, angular-material, pipe

I'm working with Angular 7. I have to create dynamically a nested material menu from the result of a groupby pipe. I get my data in the view but the menu does not trigger anything when root items are clicked.
I have no error reported from angular.

Everything works perfectly if I bind my menu on a raw grouped data.

Here's my custom Pipe :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'GroupByCategoryPipe',
    pure: false
})
export class GroupByCategoryPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(collection: Array<any>): Array<any> {

        if(!collection) {
            return null;
        }

        const groupedCollection = collection
          .filter(item => item.category != null && item.category != '')
          .reduce((previous, current)=> {
                if(!previous[current.category]) {
                    previous[current.category] = [current];
                }
                else {
                    previous[current.category].push(current);
                }

            return previous;
        }, {});

        return Object.keys(groupedCollection).map(key => ({
            label: key,
            settings: groupedCollection[key]
        }));
    }
}
```

Here's the code of my view

```
<span *ngFor="let category of settings | GroupByCategoryPipe">

    <button mat-raised-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="childMenu">
      {{category.label}}
    </button>

    <mat-menu #childMenu="matMenu">

      <ng-container matMenuContent *ngFor="let setting of category.settings">
        <button mat-menu-item>
            {{setting.name}}
        </button>
      </ng-container>

    </mat-menu>

</span>
```

I tried to make an [example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twa5gj) and I encoutered the same issue.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for any ideas or helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.
If you set the pipe to be "pure" (pure:true), it works. I suppose this is because of this:

*Angular executes an impure pipe during every component change detection cycle. An impure pipe is called often, as often as every keystroke or mouse-move.*
([official doc](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-and-impure-pipes))

I suppose that the menu fires change detection cycle, and the pipe is called again...